# Using Formula Field Syntax In Apex

Tags: apex, formula

I have a complicated formula field that calculates the months between a start / end date on an OpportunityProduct. This formula takes into account many edge cases, and is subsequently used in our calculation of UnitPrice.

```
no_of_Months__c = 
( 
(Year_End_Date__c * 12) /* Calculate years as Number of Months */ 
+ Month_End_Date__c /* Add Number of Months */ 
+ ( 
DAY(End_Date__c) /* Add Day of Month / Number of Days in Month. Returns month percentage as a Decimal */ 
/ DAY(DATE( 
IF(Month_End_Date__c = 12, Year_End_Date__c + 1, Year_End_Date__c), 
/* Can't create a date with 13 months so need to add a year if in December */ 
IF(Month_End_Date__c = 12, 1, Month_End_Date__c+1), 
1) -1) /* Need to find number of Days in Month by taking the Day from the 1st of next month - 1 day */ 
) 
) 
- ( 
(Year_Start_Date__c * 12) 
+ Month_Start_Date__c 
+ (IF(DAY(Start_Date__c) = 1, 0, ( 
DAY(Start_Date__c) - 1) /* Slight Difference here to subtract a day. We want to go from Start of day on StartDate to End of Day on EndDate*/ 
/ DAY(DATE( 
IF(Month_Start_Date__c = 12, Year_Start_Date__c + 1, Year_Start_Date__c), 
IF(Month_Start_Date__c = 12, 1, Month_Start_Date__c+1), 
1) -1) 
)
```

When a new OpportunityProduct is being created on the fly, I am unable to reference this formula field for obvious reasons (the record doesn't exist yet), so I have to manually calculate the number of months and use that in the UnitPrice calculation. Is there a way to copy this formula logic into my apex class easily, or do I have to rewrite this calculation using entirely new syntax? I am not the original author of the formula, so I would like to avoid the latter if possible.

Comment: We need more insight into the types of all these fields and what data they contain.

Comment: @AdrianLarson [Year/Month]_[Start/End]_Date__c are just the years / months of those particular fields.. very simple formulas, I've just removed them from this due to compile size

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

`someSObject.recalculateFormulas();`

Source:  https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/96803