# Formula fields in Test class is not calculating correctly even after querying them

Tags: unit-test, formula-field

I have a controller class that basically has some functionality which runs according to the values of two formula fields. Now when I am writing test class for it, the values of these two formula field aren't getting calculated and always return 0. I have added values for all the fields which are required to calculate the formulas and queried them after the record is inserted in Test class but in debug logs I see the values are always 0.

The formula fields:

- Tot_SalesPrice_Calc__c
- Tot_MarginPercent_Calc__c
- Tot_Cost_Calc__c

---

*Tot_SalesPrice_Calc__c*

`Total_MainOffer_SalesPriceRounded__c + MO_Travel_Expense_Sales_Price_SCT__c`

---

*Tot_MarginPercent_Calc__c*

```
IF(
Tot_SalesPrice_Calc__c <> 0,
(Tot_SalesPrice_Calc__c - Tot_Cost_Calc__c )/Tot_SalesPrice_Calc__c,
0
)
```

---

*Tot_Cost_Calc__c* (used in formula above)

```
IF (MO_Tot_Cost__c > 0,
( MO_Tot_Cost__c - Project_Promotion__c + MO_Travel_Expense_Cost_SCT__c),
0)
```

---

Here is some part of my Test Class:

```
@isTest
public class SubmitforApprovalController_TestClass {
    public static Custom1__c objMO;
public static Custom1__c CreateMainOffer()
    {
        objMO = new Custom1__c();
        objMO.Name = 'Test Offer';
        objMO.Total_MainOffer_SalesPriceRounded__c = 150000;
        objMO.MO_Tot_Cost__c = 140000;
        objMO.Project_Promotion__c = 0;
        objMO.MO_Travel_Expense_Cost_SCT__c = 0;
        objMO.MO_Type_SCT__c='O2O';
        //bjMO.Generic_DocGen__r.Reference_Offer_Type__c = 'Project Fire Sol';
        return objMO;
      }

@isTest static void method1(){
        objUser=CreateUser();
        System.runAs(objUser){
          objMO = CreateMainOffer();
            objMO.Generic_DocGen__c = objGenericDocGen.id;
            insert objMO;
            Custom1__c QueriedMO = [SELECT Name,Tot_Cost_Calc__c, Tot_MarginPercent_Calc__c,Tot_SalesPrice_Calc__c FROM Custom1__c WHERE Id = :objMO.Id limit 1];
            system.debug('Marging ++++'+QueriedMO.Tot_MarginPercent_Calc__c);
            system.debug('salesprice ++++'+QueriedMO.Tot_SalesPrice_Calc__c);
 }
}
```

Comment: What are you expecting the formula values to be? I calculated 10,000 / 150,000 which would be 0.07 and could be 0 depending on what the field type / decimal places are for the formula field.

Answer (score 1):

This question may help you: [Refreshing Formula Fields Dynamically (without save)](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/3814/refreshing-formula-fields-dynamically-without-save)

You can use `someSObject.recalculateFormulas();` to refresh formula values in APEX.